# Parsing multiple values from string in jmeter response

Tags: regex, parsing, variables, jmeter

I have a string in a jmeter response that has 5 values that I am trying to parse into separate variables. Does anyone have any guidance on how I may achieve this? Or is there a better post processor I should be using?

```
<a  role="button" aria-label="Application RANUM20770" href="javascript://" onclick="changenew('ajLQ6VdK5xA3$pyWV$pII4Imx2WoN$p6OMtXEapDOiKzHYLh', 'aH$sRRQGllagYsNakUyuWhv6yV7x3q1S6HfC8Z$ptwPdTMo', 'arfpB11JptWMaFvd2xwkJyNlgHL$spkcuHbJhank$s6DONv', 'aQ877kS6ozZdrGgAFxb6mqEnzCFa09$sVWL$s68yj0rmcwr', 'a4oVRp9kcV4iber3oJSH2xQr3F6XsGB4DpCxgrMNI9y7U', 'no')" ><img src="/tm/images/idoc.gif" alt="Application RANUM20770" border=0></a>&nbsp;
```

I am using regex extractor to pull the values, for some reason the results aren't consistent. Sometimes the 2nd value pulls fine and other times it doesn't- without me changing anything.

Below are the regex expressions I am using :

```
${h_docname}" href="javascript:\/\/" onclick="changenew\('(.+?)',
'${p_vchnum_v}', '(.+?)', '
'${p_vchnum_v}', '(.+?)', '${p_ssn}'
'().+?', 'no'\)" ><img src="\/tm\/images\/idoc.gif" alt="Document ${h_docname}"
 - name="vchdoctype" value="(.+?)">
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27271080/value-extraction-by-regex-jmeter/27271771#27271771

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter uses [Perl5-style regular expressions](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/regexps.html), hence try the following configuration of the Regular Expression Extractor:

- Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `value`
- Regular Expression: `changenew\('(.+?)', '(.+?)', '(.+?)', '(.+?)', '(.+?)', 'no'\)`
- Template: `$1$`

This will result in variables like:

```
value=ajLQ6VdK5xA3$pyWV$pII4Imx2WoN$p6OMtXEapDOiKzHYLh
value_g=5
value_g0=changenew('ajLQ6VdK5xA3$pyWV$pII4Imx2WoN$p6OMtXEapDOiKzHYLh', 'aH$sRRQGllagYsNakUyuWhv6yV7x3q1S6HfC8Z$ptwPdTMo', 'arfpB11JptWMaFvd2xwkJyNlgHL$spkcuHbJhank$s6DONv', 'aQ877kS6ozZdrGgAFxb6mqEnzCFa09$sVWL$s68yj0rmcwr', 'a4oVRp9kcV4iber3oJSH2xQr3F6XsGB4DpCxgrMNI9y7U', 'no')
value_g1=ajLQ6VdK5xA3$pyWV$pII4Imx2WoN$p6OMtXEapDOiKzHYLh
value_g2=aH$sRRQGllagYsNakUyuWhv6yV7x3q1S6HfC8Z$ptwPdTMo
value_g3=arfpB11JptWMaFvd2xwkJyNlgHL$spkcuHbJhank$s6DONv
value_g4=aQ877kS6ozZdrGgAFxb6mqEnzCFa09$sVWL$s68yj0rmcwr
value_g5=a4oVRp9kcV4iber3oJSH2xQr3F6XsGB4DpCxgrMNI9y7U
```

So you will be able to use:

- `${value_g1}` - for 1st variable
- `${value_g2}` - for 2nd variable
- etc.

[image: View Results Tree - Regular Expressions]

See

- [JMeter's User Manual Entry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) for baseline information on regular expressions
- U[sing RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for more information and examples.

Comment: The first variable works, but for some reason the other four do not. I have successfully used this method in other parts of the same script to choose which matching result I want to extract but not working now. Am I missing something?

Comment: I got it to work, thanks @Dimitri, the issue is I totally ignored the "${value_g2}" part of your answer. Instead of using multiple post processors, one can just use one and specify which matching value they'd like to use in the sampler by referencing the "_g1" "_g2" using the same reference name.